# git is ignoring restored deleted file

Tags: git, cygwin

Before anybody asks, there is NO .gitignore here

I had two files: foo1.tex and foo2.yaml

I did git `rm foo1.tex foo2.yaml; git commit -m 'yada yada'`

Kept on working...

Then things changed and I needed those files back:

```
git checkout long_rev_id^ -- foo1.tex
git checkout long_rev_id^ -- foo2.yaml
```

git status shows only the yaml file, so
I went ahead and committed that one

But git can't seem to even see the foo1.tex file.  git status foo1.tex doesn't show anything about the file I asked about.  Adding -v doesn't help.

I tried to add it with every switch I could think of, and git pretends it's not even there.

By the way, the file is there and I can read it.  It doesn't seem to be permissions.

I removed the .gitignore file, so that shouldn't be an issue.

`git check-ignore -v foo1.tex` shows nothing

Does git hate .tex files? ;-)

Why would git refuse to acknowledge the file?

I'm guessing it's something to do with the fact that it had been deleted, but that doesn't explain why one file worked as expected.

How can I find out more about what git knows about this file?

I'm running git 2.17.0 in Cygwin on Windows 10, 64bit (NTFS)

Comment: I assume that it's not even showing up on untracked files, right? Check this: `git check-ignore -v foo1.tex` and let us know on the question

Comment: It is definitely not that git won't see the file because it was previously deleted; deleting and re-adding files happens all the time.  If anything it sounds as if the file had never been deleted and therefore were already in the committed state.  If you rename the file to something else (`mv foo1.tex foo1.bak`) then run `git status --no-renames`, what do you see?

Comment: The --no-renames option isn't available in git 2.17.0

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm an idiot.

Apparently I failed to actually delete the file the first time.  So git thinks it's still OK and ignores it.

User error... :-(

Thanks to everyone that offered help

Comment: No you're not. :-) Thanks for the feedback.